# Bernoulli numbers in R

Tags: r, bernoulli-numbers

I am a new in R and I couldn't find any function to calculate Bernoulli numbers without using any loops. I will be really appreciated if someone explain the mentality of calculation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.